# Center by bootstrap the registration form

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[image: Registration form]

My code is: `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">` and I am new using Bootstrap.
The form is on the left and I want as it is now to be at center, I tried col-md col-xl with different numbers.

Comment: Why did you tag `php` and `laravel` if it's a design question? You'd be better off tagging the version of `bootstrap` you're using instead.

Comment: Cause I am using Laravel and I did not have other ideas of tags.

Comment: When you're tagging a question, check your question's contents. Is there any Laravel code in there? No. Is there any PHP code at all? No. What's in there is HTML and you've mentioned Bootstrap. Doesn't it seem logical to tag the things you mention and are really having problems with?

Comment: It is not actually serious issue. Okey donkey about the tags. I will remove them and be concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `col-md-offset-3` class and instead id if that class you have to add `m-auto` class. and your form became in center of the width.

this is the demo snippet for your better understanding.

```css
.form_content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 m-auto">
        <div class="form_content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this answer will help to solve your problem.

Thank You...

Comment: Absolutely yes, it help me. Thank you.